# Are rkhunter and chrootkit still effective linux rootkit scanners?

Tags: security, rootkit, rkhunter

AFAICT neither have had much activity since the first half of 2014. Are there any other open source linux root scanners out there or reasonable commercial alternatives?

Comment: I guess your question will be closed, as product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: The question in the title might be relevant, I'll leave that to the community. But there is softwarerecs.stackexchange.com for software product recommendations which are off-topic for SF.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on whether these "are still effective", but regarding (a) alternative(s), have a look at [Linux Malware Detect aka LMD](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/). Quoting the website:

> Linux Malware Detect (LMD) is a malware scanner for Linux released under the GNU GPLv2 license, that is designed around the threats faced in shared hosted environments. It uses threat data from network edge intrusion detection systems to extract malware that is actively being used in attacks and generates signatures for detection. In addition, threat data is also derived from user submissions with the LMD checkout feature and from malware community resources. The signatures that LMD uses are MD5 file hashes and HEX pattern matches, they are also easily exported to any number of detection tools such as ClamAV.
>
> The driving force behind LMD is that there is currently limited availability of open source/restriction free tools for Linux systems that focus on malware detection and more important that get it right. Many of the AV products that perform malware detection on Linux have a very poor track record of detecting threats, especially those targeted at shared hosted environments. [...]